# В который раз... запятая и тире

Tags: пунктуация

> Переглянувшись — дальше идти или оставить всё и дёру дать? — мы побежали на звон стали и крики о помощи.

Запятая «по идее» должна быть там, где знак вопроса, но раз там знак вопроса, то запятая не нужна? Или её все равно надо поставить, но до вставной конструкции?
Нашла такое: «Давно хочется приобрести специальную посудину с суживающимся верхом – какое-то у нее смешное название? – но всё не попадается (Щерб.)», но тут без деепричастия ДО конструкции.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сравните:

*Но — чудное дело! — превратившись в англомана, Павел Петрович стал в то же время патриотом (Т.)*

*Он посмотрел на пепелище, которое окружало его, — какой ужас! — и руки бессильно опустились у него.*

На постановку запятой перед первым тире влияет только **структура левой части предложения** - никакие запятые из правой части не переносятся, они поглощаются вопросительным или восклицательным знаком, как при оформлении прямой речи.

Answer (score 1):

1) Чаще всего вопросительные и восклицательные вставные конструкции при обособлении с помощью тире располагаются в том месте предложения, где отсутствуют знаки препинания. В противном случае для обособления используются скобки, например:

"Отец-то мой, покойник (царство ему небесное!), человек был справедливый, горячий тоже был человек, не вытерпел – да и кому охота свое доброе терять? – и в суд просьбу подал" (И. Тургенев).

2) Если вставка обособляется с помощью тире, но при этом находится в том месте, где в предложении стоит запятая, то вопрос остается открытым. Такое оформление встречается редко,  да и выглядят не лучшим образом:

(а) Называли фамилии мужей и братьев, — живы ли, здоровы ли они? — как будто этот военный мог знать по именам все тысячи рабочих, дравшихся на всех фронтах (А. Т.).

(б) Давно хочется приобрести специальную посудину с суживающимся верхом — какое-то у нее смешное название? — но всё не попадается (Щерб.).

Comment: София, с пунктом 2, не согласен. Такое оформление встречается часто, особенно в художественной литературе.
С помощью тире выделяются вставные конструкции, дополняющие или поясняющие основное предложение, выражающие чувства автора и т.д ( часто в произведениях художественной литературы. Справочник-практикум.  Стр. 230.Розенталь Д. Э.

Comment: Приведите примеры: вставка должна быть вопросительной или восклицательной, обособляться с помощью тире и стоять на месте запятой.

Comment: Смотрите ссылку к дополнении к основному ответу. Там все найдете.

Comment: Давно хочется приобрести специальную посудину с суживающимся верхом — какое-то у нее смешное название? — но всё непопадается (Щерб.).

Comment: Это предложение все нашли, а другие что-то не встречаются.

Comment: Но — чудное дело! — превратившись в англомана, Павел Петрович стал в то же время патриотом (Т.)

Answer (score 0):

Вставное предложение примыкает к предшествующему деепричастию, и запятая не ставится , поскольку после вставной конструкции есть вопросительный знак.

Дополнение

[Вставные конструкции](http://yandex.ru/clck/jsredir?from=yandex.ru%3Byandsearch%3Bweb%3B%3B&text=&etext=438.LOibrFh1dP-mMsUOCtakK8wTfgZuuJ8_AS94aPs1rSIf-S5KEsFGwco_-Uh4qE1J2xpDYavii7F3aNTkKVlOnrsL4L7Y9WLOaQsG1UVhDzIFQ8lLUXS2efnFuYN-y4goC_FAPX01IVduwRn_K9HobqLsdB4yS_ZUFkAAkulS3VxLpIKSMh_A_PJt13ByoH1w.f98be5e89d8a25186b263b9ea5c2c5b8f76906c8&uuid=&state=AiuY0DBWFJ4ePaEse6rgeAjgs2pI3DW99KUdgowt9XsMCv5TMMN9UTQSQbnFqxRfy1qNK6_no62JEFvW2UZjThC5Cf5S_aZ5NHu-SKvak3zgygmnPg4NBqnV-HLHUXhePqR1MuFNtD-ZyGi2gJxs0LFcYehmDLccowj20FVjg2vzhxzrLPMql4vWeq6s55kaKA_9MhAR6Wb215GD1Ea17tdZSeyyKDy6LN9BHcy-AK-DjB75X7ru1w&data=UlNrNmk5WktYejR0eWJFYk1Ldmtxck01b09icEh6NDRmcjZGNmVseWNaeWtoQktZQ1U3cjFOeTltZjJvNkpKZXVIZk0tYkNicXdtckdhRGhXQkdWOXJ6QXFLellGeVZGU2lUbjdqS1R2bzFQblhxelpzd3Itb3pzeTJseDNCY2xtUHhKTUhKWmZMeHlPclROdGxjY3lyZ1VzQ25rWm9ZRXo1U1c1UTgyakZF&b64e=2&sign=5bb925f7cf5d432c34ac2c24e8136c88&keyno=0&l10n=ru&cts=1409931643742&mc=2.725480556997868)

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

По действующим правилам знак вопроса (и восклицания) внутри предложения может быть только пред закрывающей кавычкой или скобкой. Постановка его перед тире правилами не предусматривается. Отсюда вольности в рекомендациях. Аналогично, не может быть запятой после тире. Следовательно, или заменить тире на скобки - тогда вопрос снимается автоматически либо оставить все как есть: нарушая одно правило, сохранить верность верность остальным.

> > Или её все равно надо поставить, но до вставной конструкции?

Нет, вот такие вещи надо исключить из рассмотрения сразу.  Это путало бы читающего. Единственный случай, когда можно в некотором смысле говорить о перестановке запятой - это перенос её на место **до тире** (поскольку при встречи запятой и тире первой всегда идет запятая). Но не дальше.

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду под запятой "до тире, но не дальше"? Такая "— ," комбинация даже первокласснику не снилась.